# Looping Word Match Function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel, match

I have a list of keywords and want to see if one cell contains any one of these words.  For example if my list of keywords is (Cat, Dog, Turtle) the function would return MATCH if it was looking inside "Mr. Dogs Magic Land".  I have found a good UDF online to use as the function but when I try to loop it so it tests every word on my keyword list I get #VALUE!.  The first function is my loop while the second is the UDF match function found on the internet (sorry don't remember where but props to whoever made it.)  I've tried variations of word match functions such as InStr to no avail.

```
Function StringFind(rng(), source)
For I = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
StringFind = MyMatch(rng(I), source)
If StringFind = "MATCH" Then Exit Function
Next I
StringFind = "NO MATCH"
End Function  

Function MyMatch(FindText As String, WithinText As Variant) As String
     '
    Dim vntFind As Variant
    Dim vntWithin As Variant

    For Each vntFind In Split(UCase(FindText), " ")
        If Len(Trim(vntFind)) > 0 Then
            For Each vntWithin In Split(UCase(WithinText), " ")
                If Len(Trim(vntWithin)) > 0 Then
                    If vntFind = vntWithin Then
                        MyMatch = "MATCH"
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MyMatch = "NO MATCH"
End Function
```

Comment: yes I realize I don't need the stringfind = "NO MATCH" part after it exits the loop, but it was an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugged this in as-is in my VBE, and I couldn't even compile.

This line

```
StringFind = MyMatch(rng(I), source)
```

needs to be changed to

```
StringFind = MyMatch(rng(I).Value, source)
```

to even get it to work for me. This MAY be the cause of your problem.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I reviewed all in more detail. It looks like this will work for you. (Sorry, I didn't mean to just do it all for you, but here it is.) It probably needs some more tweaking to make it work for your needs.

The problem was that you were looking for undefined data types (added/changed main function call to `As String` and `As Range`). While the undefined types can work, I think it was confusing in seeing why the problem was coming up. I tried to set a breakpoint in the function and never even got that far because the wrong data type was being passed. Personally, I always use `Option Explicit` to help prevent issues like this from arising in my own code.

The below code will now look for the value in the first argument(`Search`, can be a "" text/`String` or a single cell/`Range`) against all the values in the second argument (`Source` a `Range` consisting of either a single or multiple cells).

```
Public Function StringFind(Search As String, Source As Range)
Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In Source.Cells
StringFind = MyMatch(Search, rngCell.Value)
If StringFind = "MATCH" Then Exit Function
Next rngCell
StringFind = "NO MATCH"
End Function

Function MyMatch(FindText As String, WithinText As Variant) As String
     '
    Dim vntFind As Variant

    For Each vntFind In Split(UCase(FindText), " ")
        If Len(Trim(vntFind)) > 0 Then
            If vntFind = Trim(UCase(WithinText)) Then
                MyMatch = "MATCH"
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MyMatch = "NO MATCH"
End Function
```

Comment: Thx, but didn't help.  Still get #VALUE!  :(

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer, so others can more easily find it!

Answer (score 3):

**1) FORMULA**

I would first offer the non-VBA solution to this particular problem since VBA isn't really needed.  This *array* formula will do the same thing.   Enter the array by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, you'll see the curly braces { } appear around your formula. Then you can copy down.

**'=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1:$F$3, A1))), "Match", "No Match")**

**2) UDF**

Using the same syntax as yours, here's how I might approach this with a UDF.

[image]

```
Function MySearch(MyRNG As Range, MyStr As String) As String
Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In MyRNG
        If LCase(MyStr) Like LCase("*" & cell & "*") Then
            MySearch = "Match"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell

    MySearch = "No Match"
End Function
```